# Change jButton transparancy /opacity/alpha

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jbutton, alpha-transparency

I have custom class in Java that extends JButton and have an image background. I can set alpha with this function in the class:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{       
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, (float) 0.5));
    super.paint(g2);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

How can set getter and setter to this function so I can control the opacity from the class that creates the button?
I need something like this:

```
MyJButton myJbtn = new MyJButton();
myJbtn.setOpacity(0.5);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an instance field `opacity` in your button class, then create setter and getters:

```
private float opacity;
//......
public setOpacity(float opacity) {
    this.opacity = opacity;
}

public void getOpacity(){
    return this.opacity
}
```

Then class repaint after setting any opacity to the button:

```
MyJButton myJbtn = new MyJButton();
myJbtn.setOpacity(0.5);
myJbtn.repaint();
```

Comment: But how I evoke the @Override public void paint(Graphics g)?

Comment: @DanM: by calling `repaint()` to the button, `myJbtn.repaint()`

Answer (score 3):

The `setOpacity` method can be implemented like this:

```
public void setOpacity(float opacity) {
    this.opacity = opacity;
    repaint();
}
```

`opacity` is an instance field that stores the current opacity. It is used by `paint` for the opacity value.

You may also want a `getOpacity` method, which is not strictly required.